# Modify some jtable cell values based on other cell values

Tags: java, jtable

I have a jtable, with editable and non-editable cells.
I would like to modify the non-editable cells based on the editable cells, with some formulas.

I tried the following:

```
int input_column = 0;
int output_column = 5;
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {

            int rowIndex = pricestable.getSelectedRow();
            int columnIndex = pricestable.getSelectedColumn();

            if (columnIndex == input_column) {
                String value1 = table.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, input_column).toString();
                //do some operations with value1 convert, it to outputvalue
                table.setValueAt(outputvalue, rowIndex, output_column);
            }
        }

    });
```

The problem is, that the tablechanged event will be called recursively...
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong, or do have any better solution?

I have seen some solutions with overwriting the setValueAt() method, 
but sometimes I need to use the combined value of two input cells to generate the output cell value, and I can add this listener after I populate the table, but can't do it if I overwrite the setValueAt()...

Comment: You shall not get endless recursion if the check with if (columnIndex == input_column) { is correct. You shall only get two TableChangeEvents,  which for two table changes is IMHO OK.

Comment: Better solution is to implement custom table model. In this model you implement all the needed logic. You can unit test the model without UI. You bind the model on the Table using (some of the existing) beans binding.

Comment: @Michal normally yes, but I print out the columnindex and it is always the input column... so this is why I am also confused...

Comment: Logical consequence is that the output_column is the same as input_index.

Comment: Where is `input_column` defines resp. set?

Comment: @Thomas I edited my code, pasted the delcaration of input and output columns...

Comment: You probably shouldn't get the cell coordinates (row and column) `pricestable` but rather get them from the event, i.e. which cells have been changed and not which cell is selected.

Comment: Could you debug/log the TableModelEvent?

Comment: @Thomas: you are right!

Comment: @Thomas thank you, it seems that this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple solution to overcome the recursive calls. The column which will be changed by your program, shouldn't be in interest of `addTableListener`. 
'colDirty' is a column with width 0px;

Sample code:

```
private void addTableListener() {
    tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
            if (tme.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
               if (tme.getColumn()!=colDirty) { // colDirty = column no which I changed value programatically
                    tableModel.setValueAt(true, tme.getFirstRow(), colDirty);
               }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thomas comment already solved it, but thanks for the late reply :)